# Determine the expression of $F(x)=\int_0^x sign(x) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a problem with a simple integral function.

I have to determine the expression of $F(x)=\int_0^x sign(x) dx$

$F(x)=\begin{cases} \int_0^x 1 dx,  x\geq 0 \\ \int_0^x -1 dx,  x< 0 \end{cases}$

There are no problem in the first integral (for $x\geq 0$) but to do the second one, since I know that $x< 0$ I think that I must use the property $\int_a^b f(x) dx=-\int_b^a f(x) dx$ and change it in

$F(x)=\begin{cases} x,  x\geq 0 \\ -\int_x^0 -1 dx,  x< 0 \end{cases}$

$F(x)=\begin{cases} x,  x\geq 0 \\ -(-x) ,  x< 0 \end{cases}$

$F(x)=\begin{cases} x,  x\geq 0 \\ x ,  x< 0 \end{cases}$

But the correct result is 
$F(x)=\begin{cases} x,  x\geq 0 \\ -x ,  x< 0 \end{cases}= \mid x\mid $

What am I missing?

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you write $\int_x^0 1 dx  = x$ instead of the correct $\int_x^0 1 dx = -x$.